# Unable to connect through "DB2 for i5/OS" option in Informatica TDM

Tags: ibm-midrange, informatica, informatica-powercenter, db2-400, jdbc-odbc

My requirement here is to Generate data in a DB2/i5 OS (AS400). so when i tried to import from Informatica Test data manager using the " DB2 for i5/OS" option under Admninistrator -> Connections, test connection is not highlighting.

So, mention what are the necessary fields required to be filled to connect with this method in INFA TDM, if someone has tried this before. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.Here is what i found regarding the above.

1.Import tables in Powercenter using ODBC connection.
2.Create an ODBC connection in Informatica Administrator -> connection tab.
3. use these connections during the runtime, by adding them in the plan in TDM.

B.Create connections in Powercenter workflow manager->relational->connections

import these in to TDM for runtime ooperations.